# Loop through code, return 3 values of E or F and 2 values of A, B, C, or D

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to execute a code in which it will return 3 values of either "E" or "F" AND also return 2 values of either A,B,C, or D. Here is what I have so far.

```
Sheets("123").Select
Dim rng As Range
Dim count As Integer

Set rng = Range("L2:L500000")
For Each cell In rng
    If Left(cell.Value, 1) = "A" Or Left(cell.Value, 1) = "B" Or _
       Left(cell.Value, 1) = "C" Or Left(cell.Value, 1) = "D" Or _
       Left(cell.Value, 1) = "E" Or Left(cell.Value, 1) = "F" Then
        cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        count = count + 1
    End If
    If count >= 5 Then Exit For
Next
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking.

Comment: Basically, the code will highlight 5 rows if the cell range has either the letters A, B, C, D, E, or F in them. However, I need a total of 3 rows returned with letters A, B, C or D and a total two rows with letters E or F.  The code also sorts the data randomly each time (as expected) but will give me varying combinations of the first set of letters with the second set of letters, i.e. 1 row of A, B, C, or D and 4 rows of E or F.

Comment: Can you give an example of expected input and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep two counters, one for A,B,C,D and one for E,F.

Based on your question (and not the contradictory numbers given in your comment), the following should do what you want:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim countABCD As Integer
Dim countEF As Integer
For Each cell In Worksheets("123").Range("L2:L500000")
    Select Case Left(cell.Value, 1)
        Case "A", "B", "C", "D"
            If countABCD < 2 Then
                cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                countABCD = countABCD + 1
            End If
        Case "E", "F"
            If countEF < 3 Then
                cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                countEF = countEF + 1
            End If
     End Select
     If countABCD = 2 And countEF = 3 Then
         Exit For
     End If
Next
```

Comment: Upvoted for your venturing into such a hard job as trying to understand what OP should actually need

Comment: @user3598756 - LOL - with the emphasis on **trying**!!

Comment: Fantastic, that was great, YowE3K. Thank you.